# Gulp-concat: wrap all js in a unique $(document)

Tags: laravel, gulp, gulp-concat

Is it possible to wrap all added `js` in a `$(document).ready(function(){` as first line and `});` as last line in cases using `gulp-concat`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [gulp-concat-util](https://github.com/mgcrea/gulp-concat-util) for this

it does concat all files, and optionally add header line & footer line to concatenated text

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat-util');

gulp.task('concat:dist', function() {
  gulp.src('scripts/{,*/}*.js')
    .pipe(concat(pkg.name + '.js', {process: function(src) { return (src.trim() + '\n').replace(/(^|\n)[ \t]*('use strict'|"use strict");?\s*/g, '$1'); }}))
    .pipe(concat.header('(function(window, document, undefined) {\n\'use strict\';\n'))
    .pipe(concat.footer('\n})(window, document);\n'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, what does `{,*/}*` do in `gulp.src`?i often use `/**/*.js` . and is `'concat:dist'` only a name or what?

Comment: `concat:dist` is only a name of a task.. you can give any name you like. also its a regex, just google gulp src regex to know more

Comment: Thanks for helping me discover this. I've been using gulp-concat but wanted to wrap everything in a SEAF - `(function() {...})();` - and this was the ticket. I'll be using `gulp-concat-util` from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, and decided to hack something together. Maybe it will be helpful to you:

```
// remove jquery/use strict from independent files
// prior to concatenation, so all files are in the same context
function removeWrap( ) {
  const readFileAsync = (filename) => {
    return new Promise( (resolve) => {
        fs.readFile('./src/js/' + filename, 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
            let lines = content.split('\n')
            lines.splice(0,2)
            lines.splice(lines.length -2)
            let newContent = lines.join('\n')
            resolve( newContent)
        })
    })
  }

  fs.readdir('./src/js', function(err, filenames) {
    filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
        readFileAsync(filename).then( content => {
            console.log( content[1] )
            fs.writeFile('./src/js-temp/' + filename, content, ()=>{})
        })
    })
  })
  return Promise.resolve('the value is ignored');
}

// concat JS files
function concatFiles() {
  return src('./src/js-temp/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(dest('./dist/js'));
}

function wrapMain() {
  let header = `$(function() {
      "use strict";\n`
  let footer = `
      });`
  fs.readFile('./dist/js/main.js', 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
      let newContent = header + content + footer
      fs.writeFile('./dist/js/main.js', newContent, ()=>{})
  })
  return Promise.resolve('the value is ignored');
}

module.exports.devJs = series(removeWrap, concatFiles, wrapMain);
```